# how to set up multiple form project with stack-like navigation

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm struggling to find how to set up a multiple form project in Visual Studio with stack-like organization(ie undo,redo history / back,forward web browser/ mobile app navigation).  So far, I have multiple forms that are related to each other but the subsequent item opens as a new window rather than replacing its preceding form.

That is to say that every time I click a button to navigate to the next page, a new window is generated with content when I'd rather have the content load on the same window, much like how web browsers usually behave.

There seems to be [How to have a user navigate multiple "screens" within one form/window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974774/how-to-have-a-user-navigate-multiple-screens-within-one-form-window) which mentions MDI, which from what I've gathered is ideal for creating a situation where multiple sub-windows are created in one main window, which is different from what I'm shooting for.  Although I'm building this using Visual Basic, I imagine that my issue is not tied to a specific .net language as it is tied to the GUI toolbox items in Visual Studio itself.  Any assistance would be much appreciated.[image]

Comment: What is the technology you use? WPF? Win forms?

Comment: Visual Basic Windows forms application in Visual Studio

Comment: MDI is the acronym for Multiple Document Interface and is designed to support multiple documents but many people use it for multiple windows. Beginners especially make the mistake of thinking it is an easy solution for multiple windows but usually it ends up being more work than other possibilities that appear to be more work.

Comment: Have you tried `form.Hide()` and `form.Show()`? This way you can visible and invisible your forms without losing it's state

Comment: Emad. I had tried that but I'd like to maintain the illusion of everything being viewed on the same page/form, as the newly generated windows appear somewhere other than where their preceding windows were located prior to their disappearance. I figure there's a commonly used solution for this particular behavior but alas, no luck.

Comment: This is a repost of [how to create web-site like navigation in visual studio project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42220836/how-to-create-web-site-like-navigation-in-visual-studio-project?rq=1), right? Can you use a C# solution? Note that this is actually two questions; (1) how to show a subform in a form (2) how to manage a stack of forms

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in a new project. Create a new VB Forms project. Before doing anything to it, create a User Control using "Project" | "Add User Control...". Give it the name "StackingControl". Add the following variables for the class:

```
Private TopText As New Label()
Private OurFormStack As New Stack(Of Form)()
```

In the "New" method after "InitializeComponent()" add:

```
    TopText.Text = "The stack is empty"
    Controls.Add(TopText)
```

We are creating a label ("TopText") and adding it to the User Control. I will explain later why we are doing that in code instead of the designer.

Also add the following methods:

```
Public Sub AddForm(ByVal f As Form)
    If OurFormStack Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ApplicationException("FormStack is null")
    End If
    Controls.Clear()
    OurFormStack.Push(f)
    f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
    f.TopLevel = False
    f.ShowInTaskbar = False
    f.Visible = True
    f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Controls.Add(f)
End Sub

Public Sub RemoveForm(ByVal f As Form)
    If OurFormStack Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ApplicationException("FormStack is null")
    End If
    Controls.Clear()
    If OurFormStack.Pop() IsNot f Then
        Throw New ApplicationException("The current form is not being removed")
    End If
    If OurFormStack.Count = 0 Then
        Controls.Add(TopText)
        Return
    End If
    Controls.Add(OurFormStack.Peek())
End Sub
```

The AddForm method will show a form and add it to the stack. RemoveForm will do the reverse. In AddForm, first we check to ensure that the stack exists. That is probably unnecessary but I am being a little over-cautious. Then we clear what is currently in the User Control, so if the TopText is there then it will  be cleared or any form will  be cleared out. Then we push the new form onto our stack. Then we do a few things that are necessary for putting a form into the User Control; we remove the border, tell Windows that the form is not a top-level window and to not show it in the Task Bar. Then we make the form visible and set the "Dock" property to "Fill" so the form fills the User Control. Then we add the form to the controls in the User Control and the form is the only thing in the User Control.

You can now build that. You might have to build it because you need the User Control to be in the Toolbox. After building the project, go to Form1 and then look at the Toolbox. At the top of the Toolbox you should see our StackingControl. Drag it and drop it onto Form1. Set the Dock property to Fill.

Then create a Form2 and Form3. For each of them, just create a label saying what they are (such as "Form Two" and "Form Three") and a button. In the button click handler, just call "Close". You don't really have to have the button; you could close the forms just by clicking the "x" in the upper-right of the forms.

Then add a menu strip to Form1. Create menu items for "Form Two", "Form Three" and "Exit". For "Exit" just call "Close()". Use the following for the other two menu items:

```
Dim f As New Form2()
AddHandler f.FormClosed, AddressOf SubForm_FormClosed
StackingControl1.AddForm(f)
```

That is for Form2. Use the same for Form3 except change the number of course. Add following method:

```
Private Sub SubForm_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
    Dim c As Form = TryCast(sender, Form)
    If c Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("sender is not a Form")
        Return
    End If
    Try
        StackingControl1.RemoveForm(c)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Notice that the menu item click handlers both use the "SubForm_FormClosed" method; that is what "AddHandler f.FormClosed, AddressOf SubForm_FormClosed" does. It sets the FormClosed event handler for the form so that Form1 knows when the other form is closed; the other forms don't need anything extra for this to work. In the FormClosed event handler we first check to be sure that we are being called for a form (it is nearly certain we are) then we call StackingControl to remove the form. StackingControl will remove the form that is in it, pop off the next one and ensure (just to be sure) that it is the one that is expected, then it will either put the TopText label into itself or it will show the next form from the stack.

Comment: A simpler method would be to make each of the forms a user-control instead.

Comment: @Trevor, when people say "better" they usually need to define what that means. Something that is better for some can be worse for others. Sometimes it is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Where did I say better?

Comment: @Trevor, yes, you said "simpler". The same concept applies; as best as I understand, they are about equal. I was going to suggest user controls but then I found the subform solution using a panel. So we have two possible solutions for Quilty Kim to choose from.

Comment: Ya, but you just need to plonk down the control. You don't need to fudge the form to look like a control.. hence..simpler. But, in this particular case, since he has the forms built already, quicker might be as you suggest ;) HAGD.

Comment: thanks, user34660.  I've run into a hiccup when following your instructions verbatim-- namely that all the code in the InitializeComponent() sub in Form1.Designer.vb issues error messages to the effect of 'RadioButton is not a member of 'Form1''.  My guess is that there is some sort of conflict between the InitializeComponent() sub in Form1.vb per the advised code and the VisualStudio generated InitializeComponent() sub in Form1.Designer.vb.  I had never worked at this particular level before so I apologize in advance.  Similarly, I've never worked with namespaces but I think I get how they're

Comment: used here.  That is, I believe the namespace is used here to subordinate the Form1, Form2, and Form3 classes to Formstack, such that the appropriate variables' values can be read across these three without too much exposure to the client.

Comment: I don't know why you are getting an error message for RadioButton; I don't have a RadioButton in my code. As for namespaces, the only thing you need to know as a beginner is that your application (project) needs to use the same namespace. I guess I will look for someplace to put my entire project so you can get that.

Comment: I totally re-wrote what I had. I don't do VB much. The previous code was converted from C#. Forget everything I said about namespaces; I did not realize that VB does not normally use namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Convert each form into a user-control and place all of those on a panel on a main-form and use their visibility property to hide and show as you need.

3 Steps to convert

```
1. Create New control, 
2. copy all the textboxes etc from the old form to the control designer
3. copy the code behind as appropriate.
```

Then do a build, the control should appear in the toolbox for the main form

If each "page" depends on other pages, you may need to add methods to each control to handle that.. Like

```
Public Sub Refresh_Controls() or some such
```

**NOTE:**

You may only want to make the BODY part be on the user-control. The Navigation arrows etc should probably be their own "common" controls.

**BTW:** You could also do this by putting everything on the same form, with nested table layout panels, hiding or showing the appropriate panel. However, that gets really hard to work with in Visual studio if there are a lot of pages. It is a little easier to maintain with user-controls.

Comment: thanks, Trevor.  So given my current situation, would you advise that I go with user34660's solution as you mentioned above or should I give this a go?  I'd like to pass the state of a form to be passed to its immediately subordinate subform as well and I'm wondering if that's where your advice about adding methods to each control would apply.